# How can I apply a mask that fades out a text of a `EditText` on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, gradient, android-text-color

I'd like to achieve that result on Android:

[image]

I already tried to use a [`LinearGradient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient) [`Shader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader), but it just applies the gradient effect in the [`EditText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText) background instead of on the Text.

Can you help me with that?

*Edit1:* Add code

```
public class CustomEditText extends AppCompatEditText {
    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        @ColorInt int startColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(
                getResources(), android.R.color.transparent, getContext().getTheme());
        @ColorInt int endColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(
                getResources(), android.R.color.black, getContext().getTheme());
        LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, getWidth(), 0, startColor, endColor, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        paint.setShader(gradient);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a custom shader with gradient on top of your edit text and it will cover the portion of the edit text and it will mask the way you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I end up solving it by setting the [`EditText.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(boolean)).

It already handles the fading gradient color on the left border.